# Oracle 9.2 migrated to 11g - Default values

Tags: oracle11g, default-value, oracle9i

We recently migrated from Oracle version 9.2 to 11g.
But some bugs appeared with the application using the database. We get the following exception:

```
ORA-01400: cannot insert null into...
```

I looked for information about the error and especially about some new features in version 11g that might be the cause.

And here I'm. I know that the old way of defining table columns with default values could not work, but I don't why, and more important how to resolve the issue.

Here's the definition of the table I can see using SQL Developer:

```
COLUMN_NAME         DATA_TYPE       NULLABLE      DATA_DEFAULT   COLUMN_ID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
REP_DOC_RECEIVED    CHAR(1 BYTE)    No            'n'            12 
...
```

When I try to insert a row with a null value for that column, the exception is thrown.

Comment: The column says nullable: no, which is probably why you can't insert a null into this column... A default value isn't automatic you still need to populate the value. Nothing has changed. Add a trigger in or just don't specify that column.

Comment: @Ben: I don't think so: *A default value isn't automatic you still need to populate the value.*, it's actually the other way round, see my answer.

Comment: @gwu, poorly worded perhaps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default value only applies, when *no* value is provided in the insert statement. So I guess your insert makes some `insert into ... values ( ... , NULL, ...)`.

See for example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd58c/7 to show the difference:

```
-- ok
insert into a (n,REP_DOC_RECEIVED) values (1,'A');

-- ok, default is applied    
insert into a (n) values (1);

-- not ok, NOT NULL constraint violated    
insert into a (n,REP_DOC_RECEIVED) values (1,'');
```

You have to do either `NVL(...,'n')` in your insert statement or to leave out the column. And no, this didn't change in 11g.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration.
The migration was my first idea, but the real problem was that our database needs unique column names, and I added some tables with column names already existing in other tables => bug. However I don't know why the DB needs unique column names but that's another question.